# SPF record for sending emails

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf, isp, dns-zone

The website is under our server with the domain: xxxx.org.il

the client email is xxxx@yyyyyy.co.il

the email they get is from a third party

the email we sent from the website are trough one of the ISP here with authentication for one of our local emails zzzzzzz@kkkkkkkkkkkk.net.il

what would the SPF record need to be in order for email of be sent and not considered as spam?

the xxxx is reprasanting the company name, yyyyyy the email company name, zzzzzzz our email username and kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk the isp name

thanks

Comment: I'd recommend getting new domain names. `yyyyyy` and `kkkkkkkkkkkk` seem like auto-registered domains that only spammers would use.

Comment: the letters are only mask for the real ones!

Comment: Hi MadHatter, Did it to what that answered my questions :-) thanks for the advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever domain the e-mail is "From:", needs a SPF record. If your ISP's server is sending the e-mail, you need to ask them what "include" you should use. Your SPF record should look something like `v=spf1 include:mailhop.isp.net.il -all`. There may be more to the record, but you don't mention any other servers sending or receiving e-mail, so this answer does not account for them.

Comment: what if i send the email from my isp but the actual email is on another (the client's)?

Comment: I think that's explained already... Emails have a "From:" header, something like `From: noreply@example.com`. The domain `example.com` would have to have the SPF record. If the e-mail is being sent through `isp.net.il` then you need to ask them what their "include" line is, it should be similar to `include:mailhop.isp.net.il`. Take that include line and wrap it with `v=spf1` before, and `-all` after. If there are other mail servers for that domain, the SPF record gets more complicated, but you haven't mentioned anything about that...